# Instagram API returns nothing while requesting with a userid

Tags: instagram-api

I have got an `access_token` and made a request according to the official introduction. Something went wrong while requesting with other users' IDs (the IDs are valid), but it's fine while making a self-request. How could this have happened?

Official Document:

[image: official document]

Unexpected Reply:

[image: unexpected reply]

Expected Reply:

[image: expected reply]

Comment: what is the difference in your "Unexpected" and "Expected" reply screenshot?

Comment: most likely your token does not have required scope? https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

Comment: I put a wrong screenshot, "Unexpected" is like this: {"meta": {"code":400, "error_type":APINotFoundError", "error_message":"this user does not exist"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on sandbox mode with your oauth app then it is expected to get only your owned data.